# UITableView Stuck When click on UIButton

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am having a problem with implementing `UITableView`, in which each cell has a `UIImageView`, `UILabel`. I am using lazy loading as the data is retrieved from web service using JSON.

I have a button which need to remove a subview (say `UIView`) and resize the TableView.

My problem is that, when I click the button the scrolling of UITableView become dead slow. When I profiled my app, it shows leaks at UIImageView in UITableView.

Here is my code in UITableView ,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

     UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator =  [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
     activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blueColor];

     if (cell == nil){
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

         if (lblTitle==nil){
             lblTitle =[[UILabel alloc]init];
         }
         if (thumbnailImage==nil){
             thumbnailImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
         }
     }

     [cell addSubview:lblTitle];
     [cell addSubview:thumbnailImage];

// set frames for table view cell
     if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

         lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(110, 0, 210, 100);
         thumbnailImage.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 90);
         activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(40, 30, 35, 35);
         lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Papyrus" size:16.0f];
     }else{

         lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(215, 0, 590, 150);
         lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Papyrus" size:25.0f];
         thumbnailImage.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 140);
         activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(85, 45, 75, 75);
     }

     lblTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
     lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:105/255.0f green:205/255.0f blue:220/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
     lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

     thumbnailImage.tag = indexPath.row;

     // display data
     lblTitle.text = [[rssNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

     //lazy loding of images
     DataContainer *currentContainer;

     if (profImageDataContainer.count!=0)
         currentContainer= [profImageDataContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     if(currentContainer.cellImage)
         thumbnailImage.image = currentContainer.cellImage;
     else{
         //checking whether thumbnail is null
         if (![[[rssNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
         {

             if ([self checkNetworkStatus:nil]){

                 if(![[[rssNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] isEqualToString:@""] && ([[[rssNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location!=NSNotFound || [[[rssNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] rangeOfString:@".jpeg"].location!=NSNotFound || [[[rssNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] rangeOfString:@".png"].location!=NSNotFound))
                 {

                     activityIndicator.tag = indexPath.row;

                     // Start it animating and add it to the view
                     [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                     [cell addSubview:activityIndicator];
                     NSString *urlstr = [[rssNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
                     urlstr = [urlstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

                     NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];

                     thumbnailImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"albumsPlaceHolder.png"];

                     NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:imgURL,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row],activityIndicator,thumbnailImage, nil];

                     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:array];

                 }else
                 {
                     thumbnailImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"albumsPlaceHolder.png"];
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 thumbnailImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"albumsPlaceHolder.png"];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             thumbnailImage.image=[[rssNewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];

         }
      }
         thumbnailImage=nil;
         lblTitle=nil;
         activityIndicator=nil;
         return cell;
 }
```

and button action

```
- (IBAction)actCloseTicker:(id)sender
{

    [self.ticker pause];
    self.ticker=nil;
    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setBool:NO forKey:@"ticker"];
    [def synchronize];
    def=nil;

    [self.tickerView removeFromSuperview];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        self.tblRSSNews.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        self.tblRSSNews.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you allocate lblTitle and thumbnailImage?

Comment: Could it be because you are not reusing the cell identifier when you are creating new cell as a result, you will not get dequeued cell with specified identifier and you are creating new cell everytime when your scrolls as your dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will not return one?

Comment: and the problem is when you scroll your tableview it addSubview to your imageview and label every time, thats wrong. do subview of your view in your if(cell == nil) block

Comment: lblTitle and thumbnailImage declared in .h file and allocated in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: no. i tried it. while usin reuseIdentifier the values in lblTitle and thumbnailImages repeates the same data at different sections

Comment: cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

Comment: i did. but still having the same problem. :-(

Comment: Move the following lines to where it is allocated lblTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
     lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:105/255.0f green:205/255.0f blue:220/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
     lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; Don't need to set this property every time your are reloading the tableview...

Comment: i appreciate your suggestion. scrolling of tableView become smoother. but the problem still there. while clicking button the tableView become dead slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code posted, your tableView was not reusing the cells created because, you are allocating the cell with `reuseIdentifier:nil`, which means each time when new cell needs to display, it will allocate a new cell and add new instance of label and imageView, which can be  a possibility of slowness. You may try changing the code like below:

```
UILabel *lblTitle = nil;
UIImageView *thumbnailImage = nil;
if (cell == nil){
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId ];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

     if (lblTitle==nil){
         lblTitle =[[UILabel alloc]init];
         lblTitle.tag = 1000;
     }
     if (thumbnailImage==nil){
         thumbnailImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
         thumbnailImage.tag = 1001;
     }
      [cell addSubview:lblTitle];
      [cell addSubview:thumbnailImage];
 }
 else{
     lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
     thumbnailImage = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
 }
```

Comment: oh.. sorry.. its not working... it repeats the previous value while scrolling down. and when the button clicked tableview is too slow...